# Break the sublists with Python

Tags: python, list, sublist, reorganize

Here's the list I want to break:

```
    List A = [[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]]], [[[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]]
```

List A has 2 sublists, each of which contains 3 pairs of coordinates. I'm wondering if I could keep the order of those coordinates, but regroup a pair of coordinate as a sublist. So here's the desired output:

```
    List B = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to a numpy array, reshape it, and then convert it back.

```py
import numpy as np

A = [[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]]], [[[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]]

npA = np.array(A)

B = npA.reshape(6, 2, 2).tolist()
```

Or, if you want it to generalize to different input sizes

```py
B = npA.reshape(npA.size // 4, 2, 2).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

As for your specific question, we can get `B` from `A[0]+A[1]`

```
>>> A = [[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]]], [[[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]]
>>> B = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]
>>> A[0] + A[1]
[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]]]
>>> A[0] + A[1] == B
True
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific requirement, You can take the first element of the list A and extend it with the second element of the list A

```
B = A[0]
B.extend(A[1])
```